# Iteradores en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito desarrollar un iterador llamado **EvA** que devuelva, uno por uno y en orden ascendente, todos los números pares mayores o iguales que 2 (`n>=2`) y menores o iguales que un número pasado como parámetro al inicializador (`m<=param`).

El problema es que solo me piden crear el iterador, no la clase ni el método inicializador y no sé como implementar el iterador sin una clase existente y sin un método de inicialización. Tampoco se como se le puede asignar nombre al iterador cuando debemos usar los métodos mágicos `__iter__` y `__next__`.

Ejemplos:

```
for i in EvA(10):
   print(i)

Output:
2
4
6
8
10

for i in EvA(15):
   print(i)

Output:
2
4
6
8
10
12
14

class Rango():
    def __init__(self, start=0, stop=0, step = 2):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.start
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current <= self.stop:
            result = self.current
            self.current += self.step
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: ¿no te estaran pidiendo mas bien una función generadora?

Answer (score 3):

Un iterador por definición es un objeto que sigue el llamado protocolo iterador, que resumiendo es cualquier objeto cuya clase implementa el método `__next__`, el método `__iter__`, que retorna `self`. Es por tanto un concepto muy genérico, puedes implementar un iterador de varias formas:

- **Crear un generador mediante una función generadora**: todo generador es un iterador (pero no al contrario). Para crear un generador solo necesitas llamar a una función con al menos una expresión `yield`. Son una forma muy simple de crear iteradores sin tener que implementar una clase en casos en los que no es necesaria una funcionalidad que la necesite.

  ```
  def EvA(stop: int):
      par = 0
      while par <= stop:
          yield par
          par += 2
  ```

  alternativamente en Python >= 3.8:

  ```
  def EvA(stop: int):
      par = 0
      while (par:= par + 2) <= stop:
          yield par
  ```
- **Crear un generador vía una expresión generadora**: es algo similar a lo anterior, simplemente es un atajo para crear generadores de forma más concisa, mediando un ciclo `for` junto a la sintaxis propia de las listas por compresión.

  ```
  stop = 15
  EvA = (par for par in range(2, stop + 2 if not stop % 2 else stop, 2))

  for n in EvA:
      print(n)
  ```
- **Crear un iterador mediante una clase que implemente el protocolo iterador**. Esto es lo que haces en tu ejemplo. En tu caso la clase `Rango` no puedes llamarla mediante `Rango(15)` porque el `15` lo recibe el argumento `start` y no el argumento `stop` como debería. Tendrías que llamarla mediante:

  ```
  for n in Rango(2, 15):
      print(n)
  ```

  o modificar la clase para que actúe de forma similar a como lo hace el builtin `range` en lo referente al número de argumentos pasados:

  ```
  class Rango():
      def __init__(self, *args):
          n_args = len(args)
          if n_args == 0:
              raise TypeError("Rango expected 1 argument, got 0")

          elif n_args > 3:
              raise TypeError(f"Rango expected at most 3 arguments, got {n_args}")

          for arg in args:
              if not isinstance(arg, int):
                  raise TypeError(f"{type(arg).__name__} object cannot be interpreted as an integer")

          if n_args == 1: 
              self.start = 2
              self.stop = args[0]
              self.step = 2

          elif n_args == 2:
              self.start, self.stop = args
              self.step = 2

          else:
              self.start, self.stop, self.step = args

      def __iter__(self):
          self.current = self.start
          return self

      def __next__(self):
          if self.current <= self.stop:
              result = self.current
              self.current += self.step
              return result
          else:
              raise StopIteration

  for n in Rango(15):
      print(n)
  ```

  o dado que tanto `step` como `start` son estáticos (2 en ambos casos), puedes simplificar la clase:

  ```
  class EvA():
      def __init__(self, stop):
          self.current = 2
          self.stop = stop

      def __iter__(self):
          return self

      def __next__(self):
          if self.current <= self.stop:
              result = self.current
              self.current += 2
              return result
          else:
              raise StopIteration


  for n in EvA(15):
      print(n)
  ```
- Usar el builtin `iter` y pasarle cualquier iterable:

  ```
  stop = 15
  EvA = iter(range(2, stop + 2 if not stop % 2 else stop, 2))

  for n in EvA:
      print(n)
  ```